# Sharing an element between jQuery UI tabs?

Tags: jquery-ui, html, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jQuery UI's tabs to divide content on my page.  I have a 'link bar' I would like to have hang at the bottom of each tab.  (The tab text will change but generally they will navigate the user left or right through tabs.)

Hosting the #linkBar div inside the first tab makes it 'look' right, inside Themeroller's border.  Putting it just outside the 'parent tab' div places the links below the theme's border.  I've tried creating a spacer div but it just pushes #linkBar down further.

Of course when the user switches to another tab, the link bar goes away.  How is ownership of elements organized between tabs?  Should I dynamically destroy the #linkBar div on the tab being navigated away from and rebuild it in the tab being navigated to?  Or is there a better way to move it between them, or just manage visibility?

I would like to have the link bar follow the content on each tab as a footer, 'floating' one or two lines below the last content of each tab (rather than having it in a fixed position relative to the tab bar).

Comment: Could you post some code or set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsFiddle.net)?

Comment: here it is - http://jsfiddle.net/v8DpH/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok ... It was simply adding the jQuery UI classes to the linkBar.  ***[Check out my working jsFiddle demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/Q5wqQ/)***

I moved the `linkBar` div out of the `tabOne` div and put it at the bottom of the `tabs` div:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="title">
      <h1>title bar</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>  
            <li><a href="#tabone">one</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#tabtwo">two</a></li>  
            <li><a href="#tabthree">three</a></li>
        </ul>  
        <div id="tabone">
            content goes here
            <br><br><br><br>more stuff<br><br><br>more stuff<br><br>
        </div>    
        <div id="tabtwo">
             content goes here...
        </div>
        <div id="tabthree">
             content goes here...
        </div>
        <div id="linkBar">
            <span id="leftLink"><< left link</span>
            <span id="rightLink">right link >></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I slightly altered the `linkBar` style by giving it a top and bottom margin as well as hiding it by default:

```
#linkBar {
    display: none;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
```

Then I simply added the jQuery UI classes to the `$linkBar`.  I slightly altered the jQuery to be more readable:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });

var $tabs = $("#tabs"),
    $linkBar = $("#linkBar");

$linkBar.addClass("ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom");
$linkBar.show();
$tabs.tabs();

$('#title').click(function() {

    $tabs.tabs('select', 0);
    return false;

});
```

*Note: You could just add `class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom"` to the `linkBar` div and be done with it.  But, I think I like it better managed in the JS.*

Comment: Works beautifully.  Assigning the element to a class may make it easier to manage later in the page.  Thank you!

Comment: @Ryan - No problem ... yea, it's totally your call on that.